# Netbeans 12.3 copies files to proc folder in Linux

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans

I've recently been wanting to start writing PHP websites again and installed Netbeans onto Linux Mint.

So I set up the project folder and the Web root as I would have done in netbeans 8.2, the last version I used.

It seems this time the files don't get copied to `/var/www/html` but instead get copied to `/proc/12424/var/www/html`.

I have tried so many combinations to try and get it to copy correctly but it does not.

So I installed Netbeans 8.2 to see if I have forgotten something in the project creation process. In 8.2 the copy process works perfectly. So what is the deal with 12.3? Does anyone know why it is copying to the proc folder and how I can change it?

Numerous Google searches has yielded no results.

Comment: @Garry, please, update the question and provide the following information: [1] version of JDK used for Netbeans (Help -> About),[2] version of LinuxMint (can use hostnamectl command), [3] and exact steps used to configure the remote connection. [4] Was it SFTP of FTP connection? [5] Have you used rsa_key authorization or just a connection with a password?
[6] Also, when uploading files, NetBeans opens separate log windows in the outputs tab. Please add output to your question, excluding the cipher names.

Comment: I actually managed to solve the issue by reinstalling 12.3 and using the JDK that came with netbeans 8.2.